# Background recording and server upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, bluetooth, audio-recording

I have an iOS app that is communicating with a bluetooth peripheral. When you tap a button on the peripheral, the app should start recording, whether it's in background or foreground.

Furthermore, there will be multiple recordings, in order to send them quickly to the server. So the app will record in chunks and then send them to the Parse database that I set up.

The chunk recording and uploading parts are working fine, but I have problems while the whole process starts in background, due to the bluetooth notification. The code that starts the recording is executed, but the completion block of the upload process is not. Maybe the recording starts but never finishes because the system stops the execution, since the app is in background?

I added the `audio` background mode so the app will be able to record in background, and I also added the `voip` background mode, since I read it will enable background network activity (which is something that I need in this case).

Unfortunately this didn't work.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but were you able to solve the problem? For me, I have a similar use case: click on a button on the BT device to start recording. However, what I observe is that no audio data is actually recorded when the app is in the background. Any idea? Thanks.